# Can I synchronize a video with DOM events?

Tags: javascript, dom, video

Nothing specific, E.g:

> I have a video [with controls(Pause, play, forward... ) in a  tag] How would you do to: when the video is in the second 30, make a div appear, then, in the second 32, make it disappear.

Thanks :)

Comment: Which video? How is it displayed? RTFM of the API you're using.

Comment: You should be more specific while posting your question!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the HTML5 `<video>` element you can use the `ontimeupdate` event to track where the playback has got to, as in this example:

```
//  display the current and remaining times
video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function () {
  //  Current time  
  var vTime = video.currentTime;
  document.getElementById("curTime").textContent = vTime.toFixed(1);
  document.getElementById("vRemaining").textContent = (vLength - vTime).toFixed(1);
}, false);
```

Thanks to Microsoft for their [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924822%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Here's a working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Video demo</title>
    <script>
        // ontimeupdate event handler
        function update(e) {
            // get the video element id so that we can retrieve the current time.
            el = document.getElementById('myVideo');

            // set the current time in the page
            document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = el.currentTime;

            // If the current time is between 10 and 15 seconds pop-up the
            // second div
            if (el.currentTime > 20 && el.currentTime <=25) {
                document.getElementById('popup').style.display='block';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('popup').style.display='none';
            }

        }

    </script>
    <style>
        video {width:300px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<video id=myVideo ontimeupdate="update()" src="http://archive.org/download/HardDriveSpinning/HardDriveWebm.webm" autoplay>Sorry - format unsupported</video>
<div id="timer"></div>
<div id="popup" style="display:none">Boo!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

See it at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s7Wm2/) (Works for Firefox and Chrome. IE doesn't like the WebM video format)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `window.setTimeout` to run a function after a specified amount of time.  This won't be enough by itself if the user is able to pause the video.  You'd have to tell us more about how you're displaying the video in order to get a more in-depth solution.

But perhaps more importantly, you might want to go back to square one and think again about what you're really trying to accomplish.  Because it seems to me that if it seems like you need to trigger DOM manipulations based on the time index of a video, there's probably a better way to do what you really want that doesn't involve that.